# Does the Swift compiler optimize empty closures?

Tags: swift

I'm curious to know whether the Swift 1.2 compiler optimizes empty closures. Are the following two statements equivalent?

1:

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
```

2:

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Dunno for sure myself, but you could find out by looking at the generated assembly in Xcode.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a valid optimization. 1 is a closure that does nothing, wheres 2 indicates no closure at all. No closure could mean "use default behavior", but an empty closure means "do nothing" which is not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

As @rickster suggested, I had a look at the generated x86 assembly of this file (simple.swift):

```
func thingWithClosure(a: Int, b: (() -> Void)?) {
    println(a)
    b?()
}


thingWithClosure(3) {
    println("i'm a closure")
}

thingWithClosure(5, nil)

thingWithClosure(2) {}
```

My assembly is pretty rusty, but I can kinda squint at it a bit...

The .main section of the unoptimized generated x86 assembly, or at least part of it, looks like this:

```
    callq   _swift_once
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process11_unsafeArgvGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS0_VSs4Int8__@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    leaq    l_metadata+16(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $32, %r9d
    movl    %r9d, %eax
    movl    $7, %r9d
    movl    %r9d, %edx
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    %rdx, -80(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    callq   _swift_allocObject
    leaq    __TF6simpleU_FT_T_(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rax)
    movq    $0, 24(%rax)
    leaq    __TPA__TTRXFo__dT__XFo_iT__iT__(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    $3, %r9d
    movl    %r9d, %edi
    movq    %rax, %rdx
        --> callq   __TF6simple16thingWithClosureFTSiGSqFT_T___T_
    movq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $5, %r9d
    movl    %r9d, %edi
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx
        --> callq   __TF6simple16thingWithClosureFTSiGSqFT_T___T_
    leaq    l_metadata2+16(%rip), %rdi
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rdx
    callq   _swift_allocObject
    leaq    __TF6simpleU0_FT_T_(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rax)
    movq    $0, 24(%rax)
    leaq    __TPA__TTRXFo__dT__XFo_iT__iT__3(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -48(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    $2, %r9d
    movl    %r9d, %edi
    movq    %rax, %rdx
        --> callq   __TF6simple16thingWithClosureFTSiGSqFT_T___T_
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $96, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

I've pointed out where the function is called with `-->`. Looking a few instructions up from each `callq` instruction, you can see where the `a` argument is moved into the `r9d` register.

Similarly, the optimized output:

```
    callq   _swift_once
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process11_unsafeArgvGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS0_VSs4Int8__@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %r14, (%rax)
    movq    $3, -24(%rbp)
    movq    __TMdSi@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx
    addq    $8, %rbx
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
    leaq    L___unnamed_1(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
    movq    $13, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    movq    __TMdSS@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    addq    $8, %rsi
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
        --> callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
    movq    $5, -56(%rbp)
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
        --> callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
    movq    $2, -64(%rbp)
    leaq    -64(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
        --> callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Here, the compiler has inlined the function, so I've pointed out the `println` calls with `-->` instead.

I took an intro to x86 assembly using an emulated 16-bit cpu years ago, so I'm not going to pretend I know exactly what's going on here, but it appears to me that when compiled with `-O`, the compiler does emit roughly equivalent code (in terms of instruction count, but maybe not in terms of memory look-ups, etc). It seems like the calls to `println` are interspersed with `leaq` (load effective address) instructions, so we could be jumping all over the place, but I'm not sure where (could be more instructions? could be loading static data?), or if it matters.

The unoptimized version emits noticeably more instructions for the `nil` parameter case, so the major difference may be debug performance.

Of course, this is x86, so it may be entirely different on ARM.... Perhaps the ARM assembly, LLVM IR, or Swift IR outputs would shed more light?

If anyone with a better understanding can clarify, I'll gladly update this answer.